# Splitting the digits of an integer into groups of 1, 2, 3 etc. digits

Tags: python

I want to write a program to split an integer's digits into groups of `n` digits, assuming that the number of digits is divisible by `n`.

For example, say I had the integer `123456789`, and `n=3`, this would produce the list:

```
[123, 456, 789]
```

Or if the number was `12345678`, and `n=2`, I would want the list:

```
[12, 34, 56, 78]
```

So the order of the digits remains the same. It is okay if the numbers in the list are strings, as this is easy to change.

EDIT: I apologise it seems that this question has already been asked. I shall look there for answers. Thank you to those who answered.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Which one did you try and what went wrong? Show us.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far. Stack Overflow is not free code-writing service.

Comment: There are dozens of questions similar to this already; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Comment: Are you sure you want to leave off the last `9` in your second example?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create a generator `function`

```
def split_by_n( seq, n ):
    """A generator to divide a sequence into chunks of n units."""
    seq = str(seq)
    while seq:
        yield int(seq[:n])
        seq = seq[n:]

>>>list(split_by_n(1234567890,2))
[12, 34, 56, 78, 90]
```